# The maximum of the first Laplacian eigenvalue under Dirichlet condition with fixed volume and diameter

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Denote $\lambda_1(\Omega)$ be the first eigenvalue of $-\Delta$ under Dirichlet condition, where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. If we select $\Omega$ to be a rectangle, it's easy to know that
$$
\max_{|\Omega|\leq\pi}\lambda_1(\Omega)=\infty.
$$
Therefore, it is straightforward to consider the case with fixed diameter. My question is how to compute the following quality?
$$
\max_{{\rm diam}(\Omega)= 2,\,\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2}\lambda_1(\Omega)?
$$
From the condition, we know $|\Omega|\leq C$ with some universal constant. But this condition seems of no use.

Any help will be appreciated a lot!

Comment: I think $\sup$ is more suitable than $\max$. But interesting question.

Comment: Are you able to say explicitly what the admissible set of domains $\Omega$ is? Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but can't you just take smaller squares as before to conclude that it must be $+\infty$?

Comment: Also, a good thing to keep in mind is that when $\Omega$ is 'small' in some sense then $\lambda_1(\Omega)$ is big. For example, the Faber-Krahn inequality gives that $\lambda_1(\Omega) \geqslant C \vert \Omega \vert^{-2/n}$, (of course here $n=2$) so as the volume of $\Omega$ decreases to zero, $\lambda_1(\Omega)$ must blow up.

Comment: I understand! So if we change the diameter condition into an equality, what will happen? I’ve edited!

Comment: oh it seems also that the eigenvalue will blow up

Comment: @Frankie Yes, it will still blow up because you can consider a sequence of rectangles with one side length $2$ and the other side length getting smaller and smaller. The volume of these rectangles goes to zero, so the first eigenvalue blows-up

Comment: @JackT Good observation. You should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $$  \sup_{\Omega \in \mathcal A}\lambda_1(\Omega)=+\infty$$ where $\mathcal A $ the collection of open sets $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^2$ with $\operatorname {diam} \Omega=2.$ Indeed, let $$ \Omega_k = (-1/k,1/k) \times (-\sqrt{1-\frac1{k^2}},\sqrt{1-\frac1{k^2}}). $$ Each $\Omega_k$ is a subset of the unit ball $B_1$ and the corners of each $\Omega_k$ are on $\partial B_1$, so $\operatorname{diam} \Omega_k =2$. But, $$\vert \Omega_k \vert = 4 \frac 1 k \sqrt{1-\frac 1 {k^2}} \to 0$$ as $k\to \infty$, so $$\lambda_1(\Omega_k) \geqslant C \vert \Omega_k \vert^{-1} \to + \infty  $$ as $k \to \infty$ which implies the result.